# SP 2013 How do I switch between content type if the list uses infoppath forms for each content type?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, content-type

I created a sharepoint 2013 list that has 2 or 3 content types (L1, L2 L3) that share some fields. This is really nice because a user can start at Level 1, then switch content to Level 2 via the edit screen. So they can see shared columns and new columns if they switch to L2.
However I converted the forms to infopath forms for each content type and now I lost the dropdown to switch between content types. How can I allow ease of use of switching between content-types and use infopath forms as well? All i could find was using workflows to switch between content-types, but a requirement is it is at the users discretion so it would be cumbersome for someone to wittle down to a workflow to do it.